# Custom script in NPM package.json is ignored, runs as standalone

Tags: node.js, package.json

in my package.json I have these scripts:

```
"scripts": 
{
 "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint src",
 "build": "npm run clean && npm run dev && npm run prod",
 "tsc": "./node_modules/.bin/tsc",
 "dev": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.dev.js",
 "prod": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.prod.js",
 "clean": "del /q inet-henge*.js* dist",
 "watch": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.dev.js --watch",
 "postinstall": "copy inet-henge.js \"..\\flask\\customer_topology\\static\""
}
```

But for some reason postinstall is completely ignored when i run **npm run build**. When I run it as standalone script, it runs, the file is copied to the new location. Path is correct. What could be the problem, I am on Windows

Comment: Why would you expect `postinstall` run run after `build`? 

`postinstall` runs after your project is installed with `npm install`. If you want it to run after `build` then it needs to be called `postbuild`

Comment: @xdumaine thank you very much, i did not know that these are reserved keywords, postbuild worked, please put it as answer to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`post<x>` runs after `<x>` so `postinstall` runs after `install` and if you want a script to run after `build` it should be called `postbuild` See https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/scripts for more details.